# Avoid pressing enter with getch() on Linux ( GCC ) "No-echo"

Tags: c

In the next code: I don't have to press Enter to get the character with getch() and this is only applicable on Windows (mingw) . I am programming a simple stopwatch which reacts if a keyboard-key is pressed without the need to press ENTER, but the same thing doesn't work on Linux ( GCC ). And I have to find a solution only using getch() with no echo. I've been Googling around with no luck.  Thank you in advance.
PS: I am a c/c++ beginner.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {
  printf("\n\t\tStopwatch \n\n \t Press S to start \n\n");
  time_t start;
  char c ;
  struct tm tm ;
  do {
    c=getch(); /*get the Character without pressing ENTER*/
    if (c!= 'S' && c!= 's') printf("\nWrong key. Please press'S' to Start\n");
  } while(c!= 'S' && c!= 's');
  start=time(NULL);
  tm = *localtime(&start);
  printf("\n Starting time :: %d:%d:%d \n", tm.tm_hour, tm.tm_min, tm.tm_sec);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to have a complete (Windows+MinGW?) program as example (so if someone wants to test it, they can just copy-paste and verify). Then, to clarify, you are asking how to achieve the same on Linux?

Comment: Thank you for your answer . Yes my question was : how to get a character using getch() without echo and without pressing ENTER

Comment: Have in mind, that getch() is a non-standard function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unix (and so Linux) have a concept of terminal (TTY) which can be pretty complicated.
Every process can be associated with a terminal (and lot actually are).
This terminal has different options like the ECHO you mentioned and the LINE BUFFER (which is the enter problem which you reported).
To set a terminal the low level APIs are termios (see "man termios").
Another more friendly API is ncurses (see "man ncurses"). For instance at https://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man3/curs_inopts.3.asp you can see some function for different settings.

An easy example with ncurses (you can compile with "gcc -O2 source.c -o output -lncurses"):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ncurses.h>

int main(void)
{
        initscr();
        cbreak();
        noecho();
        int n = getch();
        printf("%d %c\n", n, n);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply . So you mean there is a solution to get rid of the ENTER on linux ? Sorry i'm still a beginner